# How to configure glassfish or Tomcat server with netbeans Ide in ubuntu 14.04 in 32-bit System

Tags: glassfish, ubuntu-14.04, netbeans-8

In ubuntu 14.04,i tried to configure glassfidh sever in netbeans. I am also following below steps.
But it could not configured.

```
Step 1: wget http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1/release/glassfish-4.1.zip  
Step 2: unzip glassfish-4.1.zip -d /opt/   
Step 3: nano ~/.profile   
Step 4: source ~/.profile  
Step 5: asadmin start-domain
```

***step 1 to step 4***, there is no problem but at step 5 there is problem like:

> No command 'asadmin' found, did you mean:         Command 'acsadmin'
>   from package 'ion' (universe)     Command 'amadmin' from package
>   'amanda-server' (universe)    asadmin: command not found

i am following above steps, if i am wrong please correct me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `asadmin` tool is located in the `glassfish4` directory that you unzipped. The error message is Ubuntu telling you that it doesn't know of any command named `asadmin`.

You will need to specify where the `asadmin` tool is for Ubuntu to interact with it. If you are in the same directory, this means using:

```
./asadmin start-domain
```

If you want to be able to start GlassFish like this regardless of the directory, it would be best to install GlassFish as a service as follows:

```
./asadmin create-service
```

You should then be able to run something like the following from any terminal window:

```
service GlassFish_domain1 start
service GlassFish_domain1 stop
service GlassFish_domain1 restart
```

Find out more details about the options for the command by using the following:

```
./asadmin help create-service
```

Comment: please sir add in details.

Comment: What details do you need?